# Which field types are supported for salesforce sharing rule?

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

Which field types are supported for salesforce sharing rule?

Looks like certain field types are not supported in salesforce criteria-based sharing rule, like LongTextArea.

However, I cannot find in [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rules_criteria.htm&type=5) any definite list of field types which are supported.

Do you know the list of field types which are supported or where this can be found in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it is on the parent page

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rule_types.htm&type=5

> You can create criteria-based sharing rules for accounts, assets,
> campaigns, cases, contacts, leads, opportunities, work orders, and
> custom objects. For the sharing criteria, record types and these field
> types are supported.

- Auto Number
- Checkbox
- Date
- Date/Time
- Email
- Lookup Relationship (to user ID or queue ID)
- Number
- Percent
- Phone
- Picklist
- Text
- Text Area
- URL